# How to remove Mime type info with MTOM enabled in CXF 3?

Tags: java, spring, soap, cxf, cxf-client

I upgraded from CXF 2.7.X to CXF 3.1.4 and with MTOM enabled (just like in 2.7.x) the received response in the client still contains Mime type info:

```
--uuid:cacb0df1-911c-4440-bdf6-e7b6bfcaa5e1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/ ......
```

As such that the XML parser (`ValidatingStreamReader`) complaints about illegal characters being present.

If I disable, MTOM it works just fine (Spring config):

```
<entry key="mtom-enabled" value="false"/>
```

If I don't send MTOM, the other party apparently doesn't send a MTOM message back.

Notes:

- I use CXF `WSS4JStaxOutInterceptor` and `WSS4JStaxInInterceptor` interceptors
  to sign the message (see Spring config below).
- I use `http:conduit` with trusted key store for https traffic.
- See the CXF Spring config below.

Any idea how to configure CXF such that MTOM can be enabled in my case, or what causes this mime type info to be present after the upgrade ?

```
<jaxws:client id="preProductionAanleveren" serviceClass="com.company.Service” address="${pre.production.url.delivery}">

    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="preProductionSigningInterceptorIn"/>
        <ref bean="preProductionWsaSignaturePartsInterceptor"/>
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>

    <jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="preProductionSigningInterceptorOut"/>
        <ref bean="preProductionWsaSignaturePartsInterceptor"/>
    </jaxws:outInterceptors>

    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="mtom-enabled" value="false"/> 
        <entry key="signatureParts" value="{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Timestamp;
                    {Element}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body"/>
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:client>

<!-- It will dynamically set the WSA signing parts if required, depending if they contain any value. See: http://davidvaleri.wordpress.com/2010/09/15/signing-ws-addressing-headers-in-apache-cxf/ -->
<bean id="preProductionWsaSignaturePartsInterceptor" class="com.company.StaxDynamicWsaSignaturePartsInterceptor"/>

<bean id="preProductionSigningInterceptorOut" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JStaxOutInterceptor">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="action" value="Timestamp Signature"/>
            <entry key="timeToLive" value="300" />
            <entry key="user" value="${pre.production.keystore.private.sign.key.alias}"/>
            <entry key="passwordCallbackRef" value-ref="preProductionPwdCallback"/> 
            <entry key="signatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference" />

<bean id="preProductionSigningInterceptorIn" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JStaxInInterceptor">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="action" value="Timestamp Signature"/>
            <entry key="signaturePropRefId" value="cryptoProperties"/>
            <entry key="cryptoProperties" value-ref="preProductionCryptoProperties"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="preProductionPwdCallback" class="com.company.ClientKeystorePasswordCallback">
   <property name="passwords">
     <util:map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
       <entry key="${pre.production.keystore.private.sign.key.alias}" value="${pre.production.keystore.private.sign.key.pwd}"/>
     </util:map>
   </property>
</bean>

<util:properties id="preProductionCryptoProperties">
    <prop key="org.apache.wss4j.crypto.merlin.keystore.file">${pre.production.keystore.private}</prop>
    <prop key="org.apache.wss4j.crypto.merlin.keystore.password">${pre.production.keystore.private.pwd}</prop>

    <prop key="org.apache.wss4j.crypto.merlin.truststore.file">${pre.production.keystore.trusted}</prop>
    <prop key="org.apache.wss4j.crypto.merlin.truststore.password">${pre.production.keystore.trusted.pwd}</prop>
</util:properties>
```